# How to work collaboratively with previous supervisors?

Tags: postdocs, collaboration, visiting

I am a PhD from institute-A, recently completed 1 year postdoc from institute-B and now joined as a postdoc in another institute-C. I have  few pending works in my previous institutes A and B. So I would like to work collaboratively with my previous supervisors so that I can finish those works and get more publication. In a recent conversation, my previous supervisor of institute-B has offered me a visiting scientist position (no salary; only DA, accommodation and airfair) for 3 months to finish my pending works. My question is can I accept this offer being a postdoc in institute-C?

I will definitely ask to my current supervisor and administration office about it, but I need some feedback before asking to my current supervisor. Is it really possible to visit for few months to my previous institute and work collaboratively to finish my pending works or take joint works and then return back?

Comment: It's a reasonable thing to ask your supervisor in Institute B. You may also want to consider remote collaboration.

Comment: Three months spent at institute-B is three months lost at institute-C. So unless there is something in it for your current supervisor, he/she would find it very difficult to justify your three months leave (it is rather long).